# Parse Query Constraints Contained In with list of pointer (where, $in)

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have two tables in Parse : `Product` and `Introduction`.

*Introduction has a pointer column `product` and a string column `status`.*

[image]

I can easily retrieve all Introductions with status "live, validated" with the following parameters to my GET Introduction Request [(Parse documentation)](https://parseplatform.github.io/docs/rest/guide/#query-constraints) :

```
{
    where =     {
        status =         {
            "$in" =             (
                live,
                validated
            );
        };
    };
}
```

Now, I would like to retrieve all Introductions with, for example, all products id egal to "Jpun01VJ3c, AkxTvIdZTQ".

I try the following parameters (I also try with only an array of ObjectId inside the `$in` : "$in" = (Jpun01VJ3c, AkxTvIdZTQ);).

```
{
    where =     {
        product =         {
            "$in" =             (
                                {
                    "__type" = Pointer;
                    className = Product;
                    objectId = Jpun01VJ3c;
                },
                                {
                    "__type" = Pointer;
                    className = Product;
                    objectId = AkxTvIdZTQ;
                }
            );
        };
    };
}
```

So, the question is : 
How can we do to retrieve Introductions with a list of products ?

Have you any suggestions ?

ps : There is no problem to retrieve only one Introduction for a specific product like this :

```
{
    where =     {
        product =         {
            "__type" = Pointer;
            className = Product;
            objectId = Jpun01VJ3c;
        };
    };
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you may want to use `matchesQuery` instead of `containedIn`.

Following code is JS but easy to translate:

```
var productQuery = new Parse.Query("Product");
productQuery.containedIn("objectId", [ YOUR LIST OF IDs ]);

var introductionQuery = new ParseQuery("Introduction");
introductionQuery.matchesQuery("product", productQuery);
introductionQuery
  .find()
  .then(function(introductions) {
    [...]
  });
```

More info on this for iOS: https://parseplatform.github.io/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#/c:objc(cs)PFQuery(im)whereKey:matchesQuery:

Comment: I tried something like this without any success...

{
    where =     {
        product =         {
            "$inQuery" =             {
                className = Product;
                objectId =                 {
                    "$in" =                     (
                        Jpun01VJ3c,
                        7CYBdVBW8X
                    );
                };
            };
        };
    };
}